# Docker image has error when running from R Studio

Tags: r, shiny, dockerfile

My Dockerfile contains the exact code as shown in the statworx website to build an image for a Shiny app. Whenever I run the following code however:

```
# Base image https://hub.docker.com/u/rocker/
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

# system libraries of general use
## install debian packages
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install 
    libxml2-dev 
    libcairo2-dev 
    libsqlite3-dev 
    libmariadbd-dev 
    libpq-dev 
    libssh2-1-dev 
    unixodbc-dev 
    libcurl4-openssl-dev 
    libssl-dev

## update system libraries
RUN apt-get update && 
    apt-get upgrade -y && 
    apt-get clean

# copy necessary files
## app folder
COPY /example-app ./app
## renv.lock file
COPY /example-app/renv.lock ./renv.lock

# install renv & restore packages
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("renv")'
RUN Rscript -e 'renv::consent(provided = TRUE)'
RUN Rscript -e 'renv::restore()'

# expose port
EXPOSE 3838

# run app on container start
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3838)"]
```

```
docker build -t my-shinyapp-image .
```

I get the following error: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: dockerfile parse error line 7: unknown instruction: LIBXML2-DEV

If I remove the LIBXML2-DEV package it gives an error on the next one. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Use `\ ` at the end of a line that continues over the next one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @HubertL, here is the Dockerfile that will work:

```
# Base image https://hub.docker.com/u/rocker/
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

# system libraries of general use
## install Debian/Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    libxml2-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libmariadbd-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev
    
## update system libraries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get clean


# copy necessary files
## app folder
COPY /example-app ./app
## renv.lock file
COPY /example-app/renv.lock ./renv.lock

# install renv & restore packages
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("renv")'
RUN Rscript -e 'renv::consent(provided = TRUE)'
RUN Rscript -e 'renv::restore()'

# expose port
EXPOSE 3838

# run app on container start
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3838)"]
```